Use Azure Data Factory to dynamically create new columns
I have a table looking like this:
id, group, stock, stockplace
1, A, 30, X
1, A, 20, Y
1, A, 10, Z
1, B, 5, EEE
1, B, 10, AAA

Now the problem: I want to have a final list with only one row per unique ID. Having the rows with its values dynamically add as new columns.
It shall look like this:
id, stockA1, stockplaceA1, stockA2, stockplaceA2, stockA3, stockplacA3, stockB1, stockplaceB1, stockB2, stockplaceB2
1, 30, X, 20, Y, 10, Z, 5, EEE, 10, AAA

So the group defines the column Name and then counting a number (A1,A2,A3,A4, B1, B2...)
What I did:
Aggregate based on ID. Then used a window transformation to pivot. But I wont get it working :/
ChatGPT already helped me some.

To get the output as your required format you can follow below procedure in data flow:
Setup the data source in dataflow and add windows function transformation to create  groupcs  column. Configure the transformation as follows:

Over:id,group,
Sort:  id
Window columns:

groupcs : concat({ group}, toString(rowNumber()) ) 




Add pivot transformation to the windows transformation and configure the transformation as follows:

Group by:  id
Pivot key:  groupcs
Pivoted columns :

stock: max({ stock})


stockplace: max({ stockplace})


The new columns will create according to the data as mentioned below:


One more Question: I have multiple colums before that flowlet. After the flowlet all those columns are not there anymore. What do I have to do so all the columns before are not gone?

Raise a new question with your requirements.

It seems there is a bug.
I have four different "groups". They are A, B, C and D.
After the window transformation it does not give me all four. Only one of the groups is adressed in the window-transformation. As a consequence also in the pivot I only have one of the groups. So my stockinformation and stockplace is always group A. But not B or C or D. Why is that? @Bhavani

Raise a new question with your requirements.
